# What are the benefits to explicitly defining a column as a VARIANT type for semi-structured data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

According to the [Snowflake documentation on VARIANT types](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#characteristics-of-a-variant), a `VARIANT` may store a value of *any* other type.

But there are several articles on [Snowflake's](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/loading-semi-structured-data#:%7E:text=Snowflake%20natively%20supports%20semi%2Dstructured,into%20columns%20of%20type%20VARIANT.) [Community](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Snowflake-JSON-Semi-Structured-Data-Load) site, on [Medium](https://medium.com/@knoldus/loading-json-data-into-snowflake-7bd3b89d5b59), and within my company where columns are *explicitly* typed as `VARIANT` in a table definition handling semi-structured data when it's already known ahead of time how the data will be structured (typically `OBJECT` or `ARRAY` for parsed semi-structured data or `STRING` for unparsed).

I'm aware that elements of `OBJECT` and `ARRAY` columns are *implicitly* of `VARIANT` type because Snowflake doesn't currently support explicitly-typed [objects](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#characteristics-of-an-object) or [arrays](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#characteristics-of-an-array).

My question is what are the benefits to explicitly using `VARIANT` as a column type, especially in use cases involving semi-structured data?

Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to give a specific answer without more details, but I usually use `VARIANT` to just not overthink this.

Comment: I think of it the other way, the only choice is VARIANT for your semi-structured data, or leaving it as a string. Which to use in any meaningful way will need to be parsed. Much the same as ALL your column can be STRING, but we mostly use Date/Timestamps, NUMBER,FLOAT for those things, as it can then just be used.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, I feel like using Date/Timestamps, NUMBER, FLOAT, etc instead of STRING is an argument specifically *for* using OBJECT or ARRAY instead of VARIANT when you know the data structure ahead of time; using VARIANT instead of a more specific type makes it riskier to use OBJECT or ARRAY specific functions and doesn't properly set expectations on what the data should look like in the same way storing a Datetime as a string would.

Answer (score 0):

The first point is "as compared to what" so a `VARIANT` or.. `STRING` which has to be PARSE_JSON or PARSE_ARRAY to use?

Next is my mental model of Snowflake, is:

- there are real types: NUMBER,TEXT,FLOAT
- there are semi-structured types: VARIANT

so while we can use the word ARRAY, or OBJECT or blar.. it's a "REAL" type or it's "VARIANT", in my mind.. so your question feels to me like "should I have my non-real data in a VARIANT or something else.., and the only other way to have VARIANT data is as a string, like in JavaScript as JSON object is a "real" type, but you can `stringify()` that, and then it's safe to transport as a string...

any ways, lets look at some SQL, verse dance inside my mental model:

```
select 123 as n
    ,system$typeof(n) as t_n
    ,n::text as t
    ,system$typeof(t) as t_t
    ,n::variant as v
    ,system$typeof(v) as t_v
    ,object_construct('n', n) as o
    ,system$typeof(v) as t_o
    ,array_construct(n) as a
    ,system$typeof(v) as t_o;
```

| col | val |
| --- | --- |
| N | 123 |
| T_N | NUMBER(3,0)[SB1] |
| T | 123 |
| T_T | VARCHAR(16777216)[LOB] |
| V | 123 |
| T_V | VARIANT[LOB] |
| O | { "n": 123 } |
| T_O | VARIANT[LOB] |
| A | [ 123 ] |
| T_O | VARIANT[LOB] |

So there, SNOWFLAKE considers it all real types, or variant.

So back to the question, you should if it's not too much hassle, store your values as real types. But if that's a hassle, VARIANT is performant enough (there is a small cost) that VARIANT can work just fine.